# Custom migration: image fields to media

Tags: 8, migrations, media

When migrating existing Drupal 7 fields, most things work.

I need to convert images (using image upload) in Drupal 7 site to reusable media.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For the D7 image files to D8 Media core entities custom update I recommend you examine this blog post for ideas:
https://chromatichq.com/blog/migrating-drupal-file-fields-media-entities-without-migrate-module

#### Example Code Snippets from the blogpost:

```
/**
 * Create media entities from existing file fields.
 */
function example_update_8401() {
  // Load all of the article and page nodes.
  $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->loadByProperties(['type' => ['article', 'page']]);
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // Verify that the file field has a value.
    if (!empty($node->field_file_image->entity)) {
      // Create the new media entity and assign it to the new field.
      $node->field_media_image->entity = example_create_media_image_entity(
        $node->field_file_image->entity,
        $node->field_file_image->alt
      );
      $node->save();
      \Drupal::logger('chromatic_image')->notice(
        sprintf('Updated image for node "%s".', $node->getTitle())
      );
    }
  }
}

use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media;

/**
 * Creates a media image entity from a file entity.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\file\FileInterface $file
 *   The existing file object.
 * @param string $alt
 *   The image alt text.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media
 *   The media entity.
 */
function example_create_media_image_entity(FileInterface $file, $alt = NULL) {
  $media_entity = Media::create([
    'bundle' => 'image',
    'uid' => '1',
    'name' => $file->alt,
    'status' => Media::PUBLISHED,
    'field_media_image' => [
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
      'alt' => $alt,
    ],
  ]);
  $media_entity->save();
  return $media_entity;
}
```

Your mileage may vary on the above approach.

Comment: Does this code work for you? I am stuck on an error with "TypeError: Argument 1 passed to example_create_media_image_entity() must be an instance of FileInterface, instance of Drupal\file\Entity\File given.

Comment: @dibs Were you able to get this working for you? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Mark I can't recall sorry, too long ago

Comment: @dibs I'm still working through this, but for now, I removed `FileInterface` type declaration from the method, and it seems to be working. I know that's not the right way to do it, but until I understand the interfaces better, it'll do.